# looking for Iphone tutorial app to search for venues around my location

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, google-maps, geolocation

I am fairly new to objective-c and Iphone developing. I was wondering, if anyone can direct me to a good tutorial on how to make a simple app that would search for a venue like Burger King and display the venues close to my location. This will be a non commercial app, mainly for me to understand how things work and get my feet wet on this category. I have done some simple mapkit app that will put a pin on a map but that's basically it. Thank you for your help on this matter.

This is a more or less an example app that I want to understand how to code.
http://itunes.apple.com/qa/app/fastfood-de/id436336483?mt=8

Thanks

SOLUTION:
for those that are on the same boat, took me a while to find something. But i came across this tutorial that in a nutshell shows you exactly what i was looking for. its s forward geocoder.

http://www.totagogo.com/2011/02/08/google-local-search-ios-code/
hope this help someone else like it helped me.

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864682/how-use-google-api-in-iphone-to-query-hotels-around-my-place

Answer (score 1):

Look here: [how use google api in iphone to query hotels around my place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864682/how-use-google-api-in-iphone-to-query-hotels-around-my-place)

You can use the response from that to get places.

Comment: thanks... that helped but i manage to find a good tutorial on that subject.   http://www.totagogo.com/2011/02/08/google-local-search-ios-code/