# Finding nearest places using GoogleAPI

Tags: iphone, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am developing an Iphone application in which i am using GoogleAPI to find the nearest Restrooms within 500 meters. But the thing i want to do is to find the places in sorted pattern starting from places whose distance is less from  current location.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864682/how-use-google-api-in-iphone-to-query-hotels-around-my-place

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i need to know that how can i identify that places i retrived is in sorted manner according to nearest distance from my location.

Comment: your could use R-Tree to find places within a range and/or k-d tree to find m-nearest places e.g., [SQLite R*Tree index](http://www.sqlite.org/rtree.html), [Millions of 3D points: How to find the 10 of them closest to a given point?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2486093/4279). These data-structures are usually hidden behind API calls on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume `restroomLocations` is the `coordinatesArray`, `userLocation` is the user current location, and that you know how to use the `CoreLocation` framework to get all users' current location. The following method will help you:

```
-(NSMutableArray *)getRelevantRestrooms:(NSArray *)restroomLocations withUsersLocation:(CLLocation *)myLocation{
    NSMutableArray *resultsArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (CLLocation *location in restroomLocations) {
        if ([location distanceFromLocation:myLocation]<=500){
            [resultsArray addObject:location];
        }
    }

    return [resultsArray autorelease];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "&rankby=distance" to get result in sorted form.

```
    var urlString = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?"
    urlString = urlString + "location=" + "\(lat)" + "," + "\(lng)"
    urlString = urlString + "&rankby=distance"
    urlString = urlString + "&type=" + poiType
    urlString = urlString + "&key=" + GOOGLE_API_KEY
```