# Get Businesses list or store list around given Latitude and longitude?

Tags: ios, google-maps, geolocation, location

Get Businesses list or store list around given Latitude and longitude?

is there any API or services for it?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093994/finding-nearest-places-using-googleapi

Comment: Duplicate question of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864682/how-use-google-api-in-iphone-to-query-hotels-around-my-place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the URL http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/ which gives you more details. You will get JSON or KML format and you can parse from there.

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple using maps.google.com.

Let's see an example here.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=YOUR_GOOGLE_API_KEY
```

Here after `location`, I have provided the lat-long values.
Then, I have supplied `radius` of `500 meters.`
I am searching for `Food` category. ( you might have any other business category.
Name for search is `harbour`. 
Supply the key `YOUR_GOOGLE_API_KEY`.